# Making sense of existing wiring for multiple switches controlling fan+light and separate light

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan

First, let me begin by saying I apologize up front if any of this is confusing or does not make any sense or if the attached diagram is clear as mud...[image: Current wiring diagram]

Ok, here goes:

I have a ceiling box that used to house a fan+light fixture (after 8 years of renting it out, it has been taken out and now I want to add a fan+light back). From that ceiling box I have 4 (four) 12-2 wires coming out of the ceiling. Now I know from troubleshooting that one of them (red arrow) is the power from the breaker, one of them is the power that goes to my range hood/light and over sink light (yellow arrow), one goes to switch #1 (blue rectangle), and the last goes to switch #5 (orange rectangle) which is a toggle with dimmer for the light at the bottom of the diagram.

I have no clue how the 12-3 wires are routed nor connected inside of the ceiling, only how they are connected at present at the switches. So I do not know how the white from the 12-3 connected to the common on switch #5 becomes TWO hot wires going to the commons on switches #2 and #3.

In my utopia, I would have 2 three-way switches (#s 1,2) controlling the light to the fan and 2 three-way switches controlling power to the fan motor (#s 3,4) as this is how I THINK it used to work, and since I currently have the orange 12-2 wire and the yellow 12-2 wire connected to the red wire coming from the breaker and the only switch that operates the other light fixture is switch #5, #s 1-4 do NOT turn that light on or off when #5 turns it on.

My other dilemma is how to wire the new fan+light fixture since there is not a 12-3 wire run to the ceiling in order to supply power from each of the switch sets to the light and fan motor separately as I've seen in almost every diagram I could find on the internet (where the red would connect to the blue power for the light).

I attempted to add pictures of each of the switches as they are currently connected but can only add two since I am new...  any assistance is greatly appreciated! The bottom pic is how the ceiling box is currently connected.

Richard

[image: Ceiling box]
[image: Switch 2/3]
[image: Switch 1]
[image: Switch 4/5]
[image: light controlled by switch 5]

Comment: Can you upload the other pics to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and post links? We can then edit them in...

Comment: Ok, not sure how to do the imgur thing but I created an account and added an album with the requested pictures in it. But not sure how to add the link to the album...

Comment: http://imgur.com/3zE6uKu

Comment: http://imgur.com/fSFQMvn

Comment: http://imgur.com/uMkySAN

Comment: What model number is the dimmer btw?

Comment: It is a Lutron TGCL-153PH-WH

Comment: The other light fixture is a LED light, and the dimmer is a LED/CFL-compatible dimmer.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the junction box for the light controlled by switch 5?

Comment: Well well well... there is a 12-3 wire inside there...   http://imgur.com/G3xw4NA

Comment: Theory test time -- remove  the retagged white from the terminal it's on on the dimmer and connect it to the hot wire coming into that box from the orange cable, then see which switches energize the red wire in the light box fed by switch 5.  (Remember to turn the power off before moving the wire and turn it back on afterwards!)

Comment: Switch #2 energized the red wire in the light box fed by switch 5. Guess that means the second set of three-way switches control that light?

Comment: Did you move the retagged white wire in that box first?  If so, that means that switch 2 and 4 are together, switch 1 and 3 are together, and switch 5 is by itself.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did as you suggested and moved the retagged white wire and connected it to the hot wire from the orange cable.

Comment: Last but not least -- can you run a new 12/3 from the switch 2/3 box to the ceiling fan box?

Comment: Not without tearing out a significant amount of either wall (behind my cabinets) or ceiling out first.

Comment: OK -- where *can* you run new cables to from the ceiling fan box?

Comment: In theory it would be easiest to run a wire from switch box #1 to the fan box since it is the shortest distance (and straightest) and I could pull the 12-2 wire out first with a string attached to it and then re-run both a 12-2 and 12-3 wire at the same time.

Comment: Can you replace the 12-2 going to switch 5 with a 12-3 instead?

Comment: I think I could, there is a short jog to the left from the ceiling box and assuming that it isn't stapled anywhere along the way.

Comment: Or actually, would it be better to run a 12/2 cable from the light box to the switch box?

Comment: Not sure how most two-stories are built but I don't have any joists running along the ceiling, I seem to have more of a mini-truss setup and I have 2x6s laying down that the drywall is drilled into.

Comment: Do you mean ANOTHER 12/2 so then I would have a 5th 12/2 wire up at the ceiling box? From which light box are you referencing to run the 12/2 from? If it's the light box that is controlled by 2 and 4, then I think that would be pretty easy.

Comment: It'd be *another* 12/2, yes, putting a 5th 12/2 up at the ceiling box.  It'd be run from the light box that is controlled by switch 5 (i.e. the one whose red wire is controlled by switches 2 and 4).

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be fairly easy to run another 12/2 from the light box controlled by switches 2 & 4 to the ceiling box where I want the fan. What would that give us the ability to control on that line? Wouldn't that line then be controlled by switches 2 & 4 in order to allow power to it? Sorry if it's a simple answer... I work on jet engines and struggle with electricity sometimes...

Comment: Would it be easier to change my utopian request to say that I could care less if the fan was only controlled by ONE switch but would like the two lights to have their own three-way switches? Since it seems to be run that way currently, correct?

Comment: Ok, need to change a bit of information I gave you... my wife said she flipped switch #2 when in fact it was switch #3 that controls the other light fixture that we swapped the hot wires for. So, that other light fixture is controlled by switches # 3 and 4, not 2 and 4.

Comment: That line would then be controlled by switches 3 and 4, and the blue cable could then be controlled by switches 1 and 2 -- which'd give you all the wires you need.  I'll put an answer together :)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for all of your help and patience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Going in circles (without making a loop)

What you want is possible with the addition of a single extra cable -- a 12-2 from the light box controlled by switch 5 to the fan box.  Once this cable is in place (turn the power off first of course):

1. Remove the retagged white wire from its screw on the dimmer (switch 5) and move it to the terminal on the dimmer that's connected to the black wire coming from the orange cable (i.e. the black hot coming in from the fan box).  This is the only change needed in this box, so you can button it up now.
2. Nut the new cable's black to the existing red, white to whites, and ground to grounds in the ceiling light-only box -- this makes the new cable an extension of the red wire in the 12/3 from switches 2 and 4 to the ceiling light box.  This finishes the ceiling light box.
3. Nut the blacks from the red, yellow, blue, and orange cables in the fan box together.
4. Nut the whites from the red, yellow, and orange cables in the fan box together.
5. Nut all the grounds in the fan box together.
6. Nut the black from the new cable to the black from the fan/light combo.
7. Nut the white from the new cable to the white from the fan/light combo.
8. Retag the white from the blue cable to a hot with some black tape, and nut it to the blue from the fan/light combo.
9. Mount the fan and button everything else back up
10. Turn the power back on and enjoy!

Note that the white from the new cable is *not* nutted to the other neutral whites in the box as that'd create a looped neutral in violation of 300.3(B)/310.10(H).  Switches 1/2 form a classical 3-way switch loop controlling the light in the fan, while 3 and 4 are considered a T-loop (where power goes to one switch and the other switch is looped from the first switch's location), and switch 5 i.e. the dimmer is wired conventionally (vs. the utterly nonsensical traveler connection that it currently has).